# How does the LibGDX Bullet extension's ContactListener work?

Tags: java, libgdx, bulletphysics

I have been reading through this blog post about using the LibGDX Bullet wrapper:
http://blog.xoppa.com/using-the-libgdx-3d-physics-bullet-wrapper-part1/

I am having trouble understanding the part about using `ContactListener` callbacks. To create a collision callback, all you do is extend the `ContactListener` class with an overridden method and then instantiate it.

Nothing else needs to be done. The code works perfectly without ever referring to the instance again. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of some things that happen behind the scenes. The bullet wrapper calls bullet via JNI. This happens mostly via the class `CollisionJNI` which has lots of static methods.

When looking at the [source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-bullet/jni/swig-src/collision/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/bullet/collision/ContactListener.java#L80) of the `ContactListener` class you will see the following constructor:

```
public ContactListener() {
    this(false);
    if (!setEvents())
        throw new com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException("Only one method per callback event can be overridden.");
    enable();
}

...

public void enable() {
    CollisionJNI.ContactListener_enable(swigCPtr, this);
}
```

As you see the constructor of `ContactListener` (which is called when you instantiate any subclass extending it as well) automatically will call `enable()` which registers this instance via JNI as the callback listener.

No black magic here :=)

If it will make you feel more comfortable, you can add a call to `myContactListener.enable()` yourself. The same way it is possible to call `myContactListener.disable()` to turn it off.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, `CollisionJNI` keeps a reference to the `ContactListener` when it is instanciated, then `btCollisionWorld.performDiscreteCollisionDetection` passes the `CollisionObject`s on to `CollisionJNI`, it performs the collision detection calculations, and fires the `ContactListener` callbacks if necessary. Is that correct?

Comment: No, `CollisionJNI` doesn't keep any references. Its only purpose is to connect libgdx and bullet via JNI. The `ContactListener` itself stores the pointer to the native C++ object (just a `long` value). However, I'm not sure how the communication from bullet -> libgdx actually works.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Then I assume on the C++ end there must also be a pointer back to the Java `ContactListener`?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. You should check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface#How_the_JNI_works